# Can a Spring Boot application make a request to itself?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Boot application that delivers pages using Freemarker as its Template Engine. The header (top part of the page) is shared for all pages.

I have a requirement to expose that HTML fragment and I did that by making a request to "http://localhost:8080/simple-page" and cutting out the parts I needed to deliver.
However, this approach didn't work outside of the local environment because the application might not be running on a different port and it is behind a proxy.

Is there a way of making a request to "/simple-page" from inside the application or at least make a relative request?

Bear in mind that any form of fully-qualified URL might not work outside the local environment.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a Spring Boot application which uses FreeMaker as template engine.

What you are trying to do, is considered a very big code smell and bad practice. In a sense you are trying to invoke the existing controller and then cut the produced `html` file after it has been compiled into what you want by processing it.

The best practice would be to create a separate controller endpoint which is based in the same template that the original endpoint was which you had to cut down, and then from that template remove the parts that you don't want. Then just call this new endpoint and it would in a clean way compile and return to you only what you want. For example this new template can contain only the header part of the template the previous endpoint used.

You can even split the templates and use in the original endpoint template a combination of header template plus the rest template and in the new endpoint use just the header template so you don't duplicate the code which is even more clean.

Comment: I agree with your answer but my scenario is a bit more complicated than that. While trying to explain why that wouldn't work in my particular case, I came up with a potential solution.

Comment: It turned out that I was able to solve the problem from Freemarker. It involves a bit of code duplication but I was able to deliver what I needed.